# How do I control which "form" of a font family is used by default in Google Chrome?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, chrome

I recently installed the Roboto font in Arch Linux using [`aur/ttf-roboto`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ttf-roboto). For some reason, Google Chrome picks Roboto Thin instead of Roboto Regular, whereas Firefox picks the Regular one:

[image]
[image]

I'd rather that Chrome use Roboto Regular, as would be expected, given the CSS rules obtained from the Developer Tools (these are the final computed values):

```
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-kerning: auto;
font-size: 14px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-weight: normal;
```

The tool also says that the rendered glyphs are from Roboto Thin.

My font preferences in Chrome use the Ubuntu and DejaVu fonts.

Comment: you'll want to do something with `fontconfig`, I guess. there's something like a solution [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/268419).

Comment: Keep in mind that Chrome/Chromium doesn't support fontconfig well https://dev.chromium.org/developers/linux-technical-faq